# error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'WebMidi'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I have an Angular workspace containing a library and its testing app.

```
projects/
├── midi-app
│   ├── browserslist
│   ├── karma.conf.js
│   ├── src
│   ├── tsconfig.app.json
│   ├── tsconfig.spec.json
│   └── tslint.json
├── midi-app-e2e
│   ├── protractor.conf.js
│   ├── src
│   └── tsconfig.e2e.json
└── midi-lib
    ├── karma.conf.js
    ├── ng-package.json
    ├── package.json
    ├── README.md
    ├── src
    ├── tsconfig.lib.json
    ├── tsconfig.spec.json
    └── tslint.json
```

I'm using the `@types/webmidi` and the VSCode editor is not complaining.

I can also successfully build the library with the `ng build midi-lib --watch` and the compilation completes.

But then, when I try to serve the application usng the `ng serve` command, from the same directory, it fails with the `error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'WebMidi'` error.

It used to serve just fine until yesterday morning when I opened up the laptop and tried to serve the application, when it failed. I had not done any code change since the day before when it served fine.

I tried cleaning up but it changed nothing:

```
rm -fr node_modules package-lock.json
npm cache clean
npm install
```

Here are some configuration files.

The `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["projects/midi-app/src/app/*"],
      "@lib/*": ["projects/midi-lib/src/lib/*"],
      "midi-lib": [
        "dist/midi-lib"
      ],
      "midi-lib/*": [
        "dist/midi-lib/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The `tsconfig-lib.json` file:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/lib",
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "../../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2018"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "annotateForClosureCompiler": true,
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

I tried adding

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
],
```

in the `tsconfig.json` file but it didn't help at all.

And I also tried removing

```
"typeRoots": [
   "../../node_modules/@types"
],
```

from the `tsconfig-lib.json` file but it again didn't help.

UPDATE: The issue is now gone and I have no idea why. Is it because I upgraded `typescript` to `3.2.4` ? Or because I removed the `webmidi 2.3.3` dependency from the `package.json` file ? High Chaparal...

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see if it work

In your tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["webmidi"] // add here
  },
  "exclude": ["test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

Comment: I gave this a try but the error remained the same. I'm not surprised. Ther is no need to specify the `webmidi` dependency as it sits under the `@types` directory which is automatically imported. In fact, specifying a `types` array only considers the listed dependencies, and ignores all others.

Answer (score 0):

The namespace is not `webmidi`, this is only the name of the `npm` package.
the namespace is `WebMidi`, so I'll suggest you add types to both `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.spec.ts` (for tests ) inside `"compilerOptions"`.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports":true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "types": [ "WebMidi" ],
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `tsconfig.json` you should add changes to `tsconfig.app.json`, because this file is used for build. For example my file looks like:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

it will work if you remove `types` field or if you add needed type inside like `types: ["webmidi"]`.

Works for me and I'm sure will works for you